# How to stop a Hive query without exiting Beeline CLI?

Tags: hadoop, hive, beeline

If I accidently start a long query, how can I stop it without exiting Beeline interface? When I use **CTRL + Z** and **CTRL + C** both stop the query but exit Beeline. Also, if I am typing a query and accidently make an typing error, is there a shortcut to delete query from start of the line and/or abandon query and start new line?

Answer (score 1):

You can do it, (Of course you need admin permission).
Fire below command to see all job ids.
`hadoop job -list`

Then use the Job ID to kill.
`hadoop job -kill <job_id>`

Another alternative would be to kill the application using (if hive is using yarn)
`yarn application -kill <application_id>`

If you are using cloudera, You can kill the SQL by using Cloudera manager (CDH). You can search by running queries and kill them from UI.